# string cleaning in python

Tags: python, pyspark

Input:

```
 " The Elephant's 4 cats. "
```

Expected Output:

```
 the elephants 4 cats
```

Code:

```
 import re

 temp1 = re.sub('\W+',' ', str).strip()
 output = temp2.lower()
```

My output:

```
 the elephant s 4 cats
```

I still have the extra space between elephant and 's'. One more problem is I am not able to remove '_' (underscore). Where am I going wrong, any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: `\W` is everything that isn't `\w`. `\w` is equivalent to `[A-Za-z0-9_]`, i.e. notice that it explicitly includes underscore, so `\W` excludes underscore.  Also, you are replacing with a space: `' '` so I'm not sure why you expect there not to be a space between "elephant" and "s"

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yea ur right found d mistake. got it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try:

```
temp1 = re.sub(r'[^\w\s_]+', '', str).strip()
```

Basically, your original \W+ means "non-word characters", which matches spaces, quotes, and periods. So it replaces them all with a "space"...which means the apostrophe gains a space.

By specifically matching non-word-non-space-non-underscore characters, you'll probably get a better replacement.